# Showing that if $A$ and $B$ are two closed sets with empty interior then their union $A\cup B$ has an empty interior as well

Tags: general-topology

Let $A$ and $B$ be closed sets in the topological space $(X, \mathcal{T})$ with empty interiors. The task is to show that then $A\cup B$ has an empty interior as well.

What I've done is that I've assume by the way of contradiction that $\mathrm{int}(A\cup B) \neq \varnothing$. Then for some $x \in A\cup B$ there exists $U \in \mathcal{T}$ such that $x \in U \subset A \cup B$. Since $A$ and $B$ and $A\cup B$ are closed, they all contain their boundary. Thus, if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint we are done, as then either $U \subset A$ or $U\subset B$ contradicting the empty interiors of $A$ and $B$. So then, suppose that $A\cap B\neq \varnothing$. Then we must have that $U \subset A \cup B$, $U\not\subset A$ and $U\not\subset B$. And I don't know how to continue from here.

I'm struggling quite a bit to finish the claimed proof. Namely, I can't figure out the important connection between a supposed open neighborhood of a point $x \in A\cup B$ and the closedness of $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$U \subset A \cup B$ implies $U\setminus A \subset B$. Also, $U\setminus A=U\cap A^{c}$ is open. Since $B$ has no interior we conclude that $U\setminus A=\emptyset$. [Any point of this set would be an interior point of $B$].  But then $ x\in U \subset A$ so $x$ is an interior point of $A$, a contradiction.

Comment: In other words, int $(A\cup B)\setminus B$ is an open subset of $A$ (because $B$ is closed) so it is empty. Similarly , int $(A\cup B)\setminus A$ is empty. So , int$ (A\cup B)$ is a subset of $A\cup B$ that is disjoint from $A$ and disjoint from $B$ so it is empty.

Answer (score 1):

To finish your proof set-up (Kavi's en Daniel's proofs are nicer though):

Suppose we have $O$ open with $x \in O \subseteq A \cup B$. We cannot have $O \subseteq A$ as $A$ has empty interior. So pick $y \in O$ with $y \notin A$. Then $y \in B$ and $y$ has a neighbourhood $V_y$ that's disjoint from $A$ (as $A$ is closed and $y \notin A$). But then $y \in V_y \cap O$, which is open, non-empty and a subset of $B$ (all its points are in $O$, so in $A \cup B$, but not in $A$, hence in $B$), a contradiction with $B$'s empty interior.

No reason to get boundaries into the argument, or make a case distinction based on disjointness. Just straightforward reasoning. Don't stop too soon...

Comment: Could you explain why in the "*[...] that's disjoint fram $A$ (as $A$ is closed...)*" you stated that $A$ is closed? I mean that why is it important that $A$ is closed when you are talking about the disjointness of $V_y$ from $A$?

Comment: @SickSeries you could take $V_y=X\setminus A$. This is open and disjoint from $A$. In general if $A$ is closed and $p \notin A$, there is an open neighbourhood of $p$ that is disjoint from $A$. That’s one of the characteristisations of closed sets.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

If $A$ and $B$ are closed, then $A = \overline{A} = \text{int}(A)\cup\partial A$ and $B = \overline{B} = \text{int}(B)\cup\partial B$.

Once $\text{int}(A) = \text{int}(B) = \varnothing$, we conclude that $A\cup B = \partial A\cup\partial B$.

Can you take it from here?